# How to use SQL view request for WFS from GeoServer: Apply PostGIS function depending of zoom

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, wfs

I have a task
to allow a single WFS request to return two different responses depending on zoom:
return usual `SELECT * FROM table` if zoom level >n and 
return `SELECT ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geom, x) FROM table` if zoom level <=n.

But I don't understand how to apply zoom level expression for parametric request to PostgreSQL. ...

Comment: WFS has no concept of zoom.

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, I understand.. But when we apply styles (css, sld) for layer, we can to manage displaying of data depending of their zoom. And It decides a request to DB . So I hope to use this aproach, but for applying or ni applying of postgis function..

Comment: then you need to make the client make a different request based on it's zoom level. Maybe two geometry columns in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be doable to add a parameter in your WFS through a SQL view: https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_sqllayers.html

Your client will have to send a parameter at the end of the request, for exemple a `zoom_level` or something like that. Then you can use this parameter in your SQL view, either with something like a `SELECT CASE WHEN zoom_level>10 THEN ST_Simplify(geom) ELSE geom END as geom` or more dynamically (for exemple compute a `tolerance` for your `ST_Simplify` with some math formula).

Be aware that adding a parameter sent to a SQL database can be dangerous, there is a field to add a verification with a REGEX in Geoserver to defend against SQL injection (it's explained in the article).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have been tryied this construction  already: 
```IF zoom_lvl > 8
 SELECT * FROM geom_standart
ELSE 
 SELECT * FROM geom_simplified
END IF;``` but I think, zoom_lvl is not defined for postgres, cause zoom_lvl doesn't links with some table field..

Comment: Read the article, the parameter should be between % `%zoom_level%` and of course it's not a postgresql variable, this request is a view you need to create in geoserver and the variable is something geoserver will be dynamically replace with the given value in your WFS request. Also, there is no `IF ELSE` in SQL that's something that exist in plsql or equivalent, I'm not sure you can do that in geoserver view. In SQL you need to write something like the exemple I've given with `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`.

Comment: thanks, I unferstand now. I face with ERROR: function key(boolean) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 46 layer, but it is other question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parametric SQL view, passing the Z value from the client.
See https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#parameterizing-sql-views

Comment: The 'Z_value' parameter should have the corresponding 'Z_field' in view/table? Say otherwise  'Z_field' has to is real exist in table for working of  'Z_value' in postgresql? If I trying to create New SQL View now , by WHERE or IF selection and add new sql view parameter I have fail do it by syntax error at or near "IF"  ```IF zoom_lvl > 8
 SELECT * FROM geom_standart 
ELSE 
 SELECT * FROM geom_simplified
END IF```