# GeoServer parametric SQL view. ERROR: function key(boolean) does not exist

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I have been had a task: to allow a single WFS request to return two different responses depending on zoom: return usual

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

if zoom level >n, and return

```
SELECT ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geom, x) FROM table
```

if zoom level <=n.

I tried to do it by this definition like in advice from [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345278/how-to-use-sql-view-request-for-wfs-from-geoserver-apply-postgis-function-depen/345302?noredirect=1#comment564214_345302):

```
SELECT wkb_geometry, ogc_fid, key
  (CASE 
  WHEN %zoom_lvl% > CAST ('8' as smallint) 
    THEN wkb_geometry=ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(wkb_geometry, 49::double precision)
  WHEN %zoom_lvl% <= CAST ('8' as smallint) 
    THEN wkb_geometry = wkb_geometry
END)

from input.admin_centers_and_districts
```

But when I try to do it I face this

> ERROR: function key(boolean) does not exist Hint: No function matches
>   the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts. Position: 46

[image]

What is wrong? `cast('8'smallint)` is useless.

Comment: That SQL snipped you posted is a little messy (no offense); there's no need to cast a string `'8'` to a number, but most of all, SQL is not comparable to procedural languages, e.g. you *cannot simply assign values* to variables (e.g. `wkb_geometry = ST_Simplify...`). That specific error results from a missing `,` between `key` and the following (unnecessarily bracket enclosed) `CASE` statement; without the comma, PostgreSQL treats that part as a function invocation (`SELECT ..., key(CASE ... END) ...`)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS is saying it can't find a function called `key` that takes a boolean operator.

```
SELECT wkb_geometry, ogc_fid, key
  (CASE 
  WHEN %zoom_lvl% > CAST ('8' as smallint) 
    THEN wkb_geometry=ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(wkb_geometry, 49::double precision)
  WHEN %zoom_lvl% <= CAST ('8' as smallint) 
    THEN wkb_geometry = wkb_geometry
END)

from input.admin_centers_and_districts
```

This is because this statement evaluates to be something like:

```
SELECT wkb_geometry, ogc_fid, key
  true
from input.admin_centers_and_districts
```

Which is nonsense. SQL might look like a programming language but it isn't really one. So you want something like

```
SELECT ogc_fid, key,
  (CASE 
  WHEN %zoom_lvl% > 8) 
    THEN ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(wkb_geometry, 49::double precision)
  else 
    wkb_geometry
END) as wkb_geometry

from input.admin_centers_and_districts
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL select, you're supposed to describre the result you want, not what to do. Here you put a lot of assignement `=`, in SQL you use it as comparison (equivalent to `==` in many languages) except in a few cases like update. If you want to rename the column of your result, you write `as new_name` at the end of the column description. I suppose that's what you wanted to do, because the way you wrote it you have `key(CASE...END)` which is interpreted as a function called with a parameter boolean because you compare something in your CASE with `=` (not found so -> error). Here is an exemple, simplified, and without `=` inside your `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    wkb_geometry, 
    ogc_fid, 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN %zoom_lvl% > 8 THEN ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(wkb_geometry, 49)
            ELSE wkb_geometry
        END
    ) as key
FROM input.admin_centers_and_districts
```